# Spring Integration JDBC inbound adapter

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have to read the rows from database and pass on the rows to service activator
with the help of rowmapper send mails with our own framework which we are able to achieve, The problem is we need to update the respective row's column with dynamic status and errorstackstrace depending success or failure in service activator method.

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="emailReqestChannel"
        query="select * from email_requests where email_request_status = 'NEW'"
        update="update email_requests set email_request_status = 'SUCCESS' where email_request_id in (:email)"
        max-rows-per-poll="10"
        data-source="dataSource" row-mapper="emailRequestRowMapper">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000">
        <int:transactional />
    </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:service-activator input-channel="emailReqestChannel" ref="emailRequestMessageHandler" />
<bean id="jdbcMessageHandler"
        class="com.company.selfservice.jdbc.handler.JdbcMessageHandler" />
<bean id="emailRequestMessageHandler"
        class="com.company.selfservice.jdbc.handler.EmailRequestMessageHandler" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<int:poller default="true" fixed-rate="10000"/>
<int:channel id="dataChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="emailReqestChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.connection_url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>
<bean id="emailRequestRowMapper"
        class="com.company.selfservice.jdbc.handler.EmailRequestRowMapper" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the story is about a `dynamic status and errorstackstrace depending success or failure`, then you shouldn't use an `update` in the `<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>`, but really consider to use `<int-jdbc:outpbund-channel-adapter>`, there you can resolve query arguments against a request message: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-outbound-channel-adapter